# Auto email response from Shopify api

Tags: api, passwords

I've successfully created a script that will import username/passwords etc into Shopify (using the api).

However, when I do this an automatic email is sent to the customer. I don't need this and can't find a way of either modifying it or turning it off. There is no mention of the email in the api documentation which has meant me finding out the hard way (by some clients complaining!)

The email is not the same one that is sent to the customer when a new account is set up. So where does it come from? How can I switch it off/modify it's contents?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some digging I found where the email message was being generated from. It is one of the default messages that are already set up in Shopify (Customer Account confirmation) under 'Emails & Notifications'.

Just make sure you change this before you start running your shop as the default message is a little 'dry'.

Thanks for your help guys.